# Change JqGrid's navGrid Edit afterComplete after Grid creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to change a navGrid's edit afterComplete function AFTER grid creation.

The specific function I'm referring to is here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to create your event handler which will be called after the user add new row to the grid? Or you mean `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` callbacks which will be called after the grid body is filled?

Comment: Specifically, after the user clicks on the Edit button, fills out the modal form, and hits submit.  I know how to set the function up on grid creation, but is there a way to set the function up AFTER creation? Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand your terminology. The user click "Edit" button then the user modify the data in the form and click "Submit" data. You can define `onclickSubmit` and `beforeSubmit`. Then the data will be send to the server and jqGrid receive the response. Now will be called `afterSubmit` in case of successful response or `errorTextFormat` in case of error. Then if the `reloadAfterSubmit` is `true` (default setting) the grid will be *reloaded* and `afterComplete` callback will be called asynchronously. What from the above events you need?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The exact function that I am looking for is afterComplete defined within the navGrid's edit section.  Right now, I have a work around in place that works like:

Comment: function editAfterComplete_grid(response, data, id) {};

jQuery("#grid").jqgrid({ ... // options })
               .navGrid(
                "#pager",
                { edit: true },
                { afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) { editAfterComplete_my_grid(response, data, id);
                }});

//The code where I change the function:

window.editAfterComplete_grid = function(response, data, id) {  // changes here };

Comment: You don't need to define `editAfterComplete_grid` as *global* function. Mostly one uses *anonymous* functions like : ` jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) { /*here any code like*/ alert("in afterComplete"); }});`